# What happens if a function is not measurable? Definition aside

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

That is, what would be the motivation for mathematicians to restrict their condition to only measurable functions. Desire for integrability is one. What else?

Comment: One is the lack of examples of nonmeasurable functions, reflected in the fact that it is consistent with ZF (not ZFC) that every subset of the reals is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: In groups we also study mostly homomorphisms. In topology, continuous functions, etc. Arbitrary functions can be too wild and make the extra structure irrelevant.

Comment: It turns out most useful functions we meet in practice (definable by formulae ) are measurable anyway.

Comment: I don't think the statement "every subset of the reals is Lebesgue measurable" is correct based on standard topology on $R^n$? What is ZF and ZFC?

Comment: @DanielLi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory

Comment: ZF are the axioms for set theory (Zermelo-Fraenkel) .ZFC are those with the axiom of choice added. Only with choice you can prove the existence of non-measurable sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you! But can you expand a little bit on how this has to do with homomorphism?

Comment: homomorphisms also preserve group/ring etc. structure, just as measurable sets are preserved by measurable functions.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Great insight! Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't desire for integrability enough of a reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every branch of mathematics uses certain sets as their basic building blocks. In measure theory these are measurable spaces, in topology topological spaces, in linear algebra vector spaces etc.

That we consider measurable spaces (i.e. a spaces endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra on them, i.e. pairs $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$) has to do with the basic abstractions of what a volume is, which leads to the notion of a **measure**. It turns out that the best way to think about which sets to measure, i.e. take "volumes" of, leads to **$\sigma$-algebras**.

Now we would like to consider maps between several such measurable spaces, i.e. $f \colon (\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{1}) \rightarrow (\Omega_{2}, \mathcal{A}_{2})$ that are "compatible" with their $\sigma$-algebras. One case of particular importance is that where you have a measure on the domain space, i.e. $f \colon (\Omega_{1}, \mathcal{A}_{1}, \mu_{1}) \rightarrow (\Omega_{2}, \mathcal{A}_{2})$. You would like to use this to define a measure $\mu_{2}$ on your target space. How would you do that?

The most natural way is to define (note that, by what I wrote above, measures "live" on $\sigma$-algebras, so we need to know what $\mu_{2}$ is on any sets from the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_{2}$)
$$
\mu_{2}(A_{2}) := \mu_{1}(f^{-1}(A_{2})).
$$
But for this to make sense, as $\mu_{1}$ "lives" on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_{1}$, we need the following condition:
$$
\forall A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}_{2}: \quad f^{-1}(A_{2}) \in \mathcal{A}_{1},
$$
i.e. the measurability of the map $f$.

*Edit*: What @HennoBrandsma has been nodding towards is the notion of a *category*. Simply speaking, in category theory you look at categories, which are the classes of objects (typically on the level of sets) that are of interest, and the ones that I mentioned in the beginning of my post (topological spaces etc.) are precisely the objects in these categories. But for things to get interesting, you need to pass from one object to another in a meaningful way. These mappings are called *morphisms*, and in each category these morphisms have different properties, all of which ensure that the structures on you objects are compatible with these mappings. So for example in the category of vector spaces (which have a linear structure, i.e. you can add and scale vectors), the morphisms are the maps that respect this linear structure, i.e. linear maps or homomorphisms. In topology the maps that respect the topology are continuous maps, and in measure theory your morphisms are measurable maps. This "categorical thinking" provides a nice way to summarise a lot of results and concepts in various branches of mathematics.

So if you have enough experience, you *expect* that there are maps that preserve the structure of your objects and that these maps play an important role. But this was all abstract nonsense, so if that is too abstract for you, just stick to the explanation given above.